# Taking grayscale picture with Android's camera2

Tags: android, grayscale, android-camera2

I am creating an app for taking pictures and sending them via http POST to my server. Since I only need grayscale data on the server side, it would by much better to just take the grayscale picture and not having to convert it. 
I am using [Camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) and I have an issue with setting properties for `CaptureRequest.Builder` instance. With this:

```
final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_NEGATIVE);
```

It takes a negative photo.
But this:

```
final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_MONO);
```

Does absolutely nothing. No grayscale. just a normal picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the list of [supported effects](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#CONTROL_AVAILABLE_EFFECTS) on your device, to see if MONO is actually supported by it.

If you only care about luminance, you could just capture YUV_420_888 buffers instead of JPEG, and only send the Y buffer to the server.  That won't get you automatic JPEG encoding, though.

Also note that generally under the hood, JPEG images are encoded in YUV; so if you dig into your JPEG decoder library, you may be able to get the image data before conversion to RGB, and simply ignore the chroma channels.

Answer (score 1):

```
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_MONO);
```

you can use this`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what you changed in the code and how this change fixes the problem, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.